# VisualStudio 2013 can't find referenced namespace

Tags: c#, visual-studio, namespaces, using

I manually add two DLLs to my project Dapper.DLL and Dapper.Contrib.DLL than create DapperTest.cs class in my project root namespace EBTests. Than I create more cs files so I created folder Dapper and move all this classes inside this folder. So far so good.

Than I add new class **inside the folder Dapper** name it DataManagerWithDapper.cs Since that using reference to Dapper.Contrib stopped working in all my classes.

Answer (score 0):

After hours of researches I found the very simple reason. My lastly added class get new namespace EBTests.Dapper and it was somehow in conflict with Dapper.Contrib. After I changed my new namespace from "EBTests.Dapper" to "EBTests", using to Dapper.Contrib starts to work properly.